# Reshaping data frame with old variables to be new rownames

Tags: r, reshape

I need to reshape my data on a way that in the columns I have the values for two different years, so I can calculate the variation. The main idea is that the user can select two different years and view the variation for different KPI's.

Suppose this is my data:

```
df <- data.frame(
  PERIOD = c(2020, 2021),
  map = c(1, 2),
  mac = c(1, 4)
)
```

I would like the new data frame to have two columns (year 2020, year 2021) and "map" "mac" to be the values of a new variable called "kpi".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)

pivot_longer(df, cols = -PERIOD, names_to = "kpi") |>
  pivot_wider(names_from = PERIOD, names_prefix = "year")
```

**Output**

```
  kpi   year2020 year2021
1 map          1        2
2 mac          1        4
```

Answer (score 5):

You could also do this in base R by transposing and tidying the names:

```r
setNames(as.data.frame(t(df)[-1,]), df[[1]])
#>     2020 2021
#> map    1    2
#> mac    1    4
```

Answer (score 3):

Using `transpose` from `data.table`

```
data.table::transpose(df, make.names = 'PERIOD', keep.names = 'kpi')
   kpi 2020 2021
1 map    1    2
2 mac    1    4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is `data.table`:

```
dcast(melt(setDT(df), id.vars = "PERIOD"), variable ~ PERIOD, value.var = "value")

   variable 2020 2021
1:      map    1    2
2:      mac    1    4
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is using package `janitor`

```
library(janitor)

t(df) %>% row_to_name(1)

#>     2020 2021
#> map    1    2
#> mac    1    4
```